# In crystal report unable to open rowset. Incorrect syntax near

Tags: crystal-reports

Failed to load rowset. Incorrect syntax near...this error comes when I run the program. I want to show report in a crystal report. I have many tables linked by key. Anyone can suggest

Comment: Can you please show the query that you use to run this report?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of database you're pulling from, but you may want to do your joins *before* you pull it into CR.

If that doesn't do it, you may want to save your data to a temporary table as well, then link CR to the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this means that Crystal Reports has build an incorrect SQL statement. This happens sometimes as f.e. with SQLBase. Mostly that is difficult to solve.

Sometimes it can be solved by using a different database driver, f.e. try to use OLEDB instead of ODBC.

If that doesn't help, please provide more details:

- Database (SQL Server, Oracle, or ...)
- Database driver: ODBC, OLEDB, or ...
- Query (via menu [Database, Show SQL Query).